# How to update a Single Character in a mysql table which contain number of Fields

Tags: mysql

I am having **Maracaïbo** as one of my fields. Now i need to update it into **Maracaibo**.

In simple i need to update the **ï** only. how can i do it.

Example:

city

**Maracaïbo**

**Mïrïda**

My O/P should be like this: (**Please note the "i" section**)

city

**Maracaibo**

**Mirida**

how can i able to update both the fields using mysql update query. How can i do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET city = REPLACE(city, 'ï', 'i')
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace